# Can I have a string of TIMESTAMPS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types, timestamp, schema

I am just wondering to know can I have a string of `TIMESTAMP`s in a MySQL table schema like following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth (
  id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  admin INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at [TIMESTAMP]
);
```

Unfortunately the above code gives me a syntax error!

My idea is to have a list of `TIMESTAM`s to store every future updates inside of it, something like `['2023-01-01' , '2023-02-02' , ....]`

If this is not possible in my suggested way, how can I store any changes of one column of a table like created_at column? Should I do it in the web-server?

Comment: Yes you can.. but not `[TIMESTAMP]`.. try `VARCHAR(255)` but what does the future dates represent? And what is the interval? every 30 days? every month?

Comment: @FanoFN: I wanna keep a track of future edit/updates of a row. For example if it is a `price` column I want to have all price changes from the first price.

Comment: @FanoFN: Isn't VARCHAR just like a simple string? You say I should manage a simple string like a list of strings? In this way isn't it easier/more efficient doing this in the web server application instead of the database?

Comment: There's no datatype in MySQL that can store multiple string of dates in the proper date format as `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. And of course, I personally don't think `VARCHAR` is much easier nor efficient to maintain.

Comment: _"I wanna keep a track of future edit/updates of a row"_ , like a log, right? How about a duplicate table that will populate any future update/change?

Comment: @FanoFN: You say only because of one column that gets updated randomly, we create another similar update? With this approach we will ended up with thousands of similar tables! I think it would be better to handle it in web server application and create a coma separated long string/VARCHAR to store it on the database, then I can call `.spleit(',')`on it whenever I fetch data and push them inside a list of strings.

Comment: I don't think we're in the same page here, how did you end up with a conclusion _"thousand of similar tables"_ despite I'm suggesting _"a duplicate table"_ , just a single table. In my case, there's only one other table that keep a log of every update so, it's actually thousands of rows instead.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, but how many columns would this new table have? Isn't it to expensive to have a table with number of rows as the number of our original table primary keys and a number oc columns of let's say 100, but they are all empty at the beginning?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle and tell me if this makes sense on what you're trying to do https://dbfiddle.uk/lJ8rydjD

Comment: @FanoFN: Will you create a new table for each user or add all the users in the same table? When I talked about thousands of tables I meant you should create a seperate table for each user.

Comment: If you don't want to create a table for each user, I think you should add another `id` column to the log table as a new primary key column.

Comment: I will definitely use only one log table for all users and yes, in my practice, my log tables does have another column for it's own primary key id. It's also better to have index on a few columns like `email`, `created_at` or `admin`... whichever column that you will use to do a search on the log table so that your query will be more efficient.